# How to remove string "\u001b[1m" in java

Tags: java, special-characters

After I receive a content response of the server, and print the content to console and I realize existing of the string "\u001b[1m", and I think it's the reason I can't parse the conte tresponse as a JSON object.

And I want to remove the string, any solution?

Answer (score 6):

That looks like an ANSI video escape sequence to turn bold mode on. Are you sure that the server is sending back a JSON object?

Comment: I'm sure, the server is yahoo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know what's actually in the string -- try examining (and maybe printing) it character by character using `someString.charAt()`.

And, `String newString = someString.replaceAll(oldexp);` is one of many ways you might try to "fix" it, if it turns out that's needed.

Comment: replaceAll() does exactly what it's told... So you need to know exactly what characters you're trying to alter.

Answer (score 0):

That's an escape sequence, and I think it's used to turn on formatting in some things like the Terminal. Is that really supposed to be JSON? What's the rest of the text? Does that escape sequence come as plain text or as one character?

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON?

Comment: I use the JSON library for java on json.org, btw, I think the problem causes the square bracket in the string "\u001b[1m"

Comment: You could just do a quick replacement - `\ ` with `\\ ` - before parsing.

Comment: do you mean content.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\")

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^

Comment: URL con = new URL("url");
  HttpURLConnection httpURLCon = (HttpURLConnection)con.openConnection();
  DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(httpURLCon.getInputStream());
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(inStream);
  String content = "";
  while (sc.hasNextLine())
   content = content + sc.nextLine();
  content.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");

Comment: Oh, no maybe: `content.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");` actually.

Comment: that's my code, the url is too long to post here, I will put the url in the first post, you can try it

Comment: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1], try my code at the first post

Answer (score 0):

During the development of an SSH program that also utilizes command line mysql commands, I created the following regex that I strip these sequences with:

```
\u001b[\[\(]([0-9];[0-9]|\?[0-9]+)?[Bmh]
```

It covers the ranges that I have run into issues with

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  -E 's/\\u001b\[[0-9][0-9]?m//g'
```